# UITableviewcontroller vs UIViewController with tableView method for didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I have trouble to make something work:

I have a UIViewController with a tableView in it that has been connected and had it's delegates set. I am trying to send a segue from didSelectRowatIndexPath and in prepareforSegue I am trying to read some of the selected cell's data (I am using the model to retrieve the actual -important- data, but I have some elements i.e. an imageView which I want to read from the cell)

What confuses me is no matter how I set the sender (self.tableView or self or indexPath or anything), in the prepareforSegue I always get the cell as nil.

If I change the UIViewController to a UITableViewController and make the sender as tableView, everything is working perfectly fine.

What am I missing?

Code Follows:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bundleItemDetails" sender:tableView];
```

}

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"bundleItemDetails"])

{

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


    itemCell *cell = (itemCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

    NSDictionary *currentProduct = [[[productsArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.section] objectForKey:@"products"] objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];


    UINavigationController *navController = [segue  destinationViewController];
    itemDetails *bundleProducts = (itemDetails*)([navController viewControllers][0]);


    UIImage *img = cell.itemImage.image;
    bundleProducts.valueImage = img;
    bundleProducts.valueName = [currentProduct valueForKey:@"title"];
    bundleProducts.valueDescription = [currentProduct valueForKey:@"description"];
    bundleProducts.detailFullPrice.text = [currentProduct valueForKey:@"price"];

}
```

}

This Works perfectly with UITableViewController and returns nil for cell values for UIViewController

**Update: Some new findings**

It looks that indexPathForSelectedRow returns null and 0. In case I change the code of didSelectRowAtIndexPath to:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                            animated:NO
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell setSelected:YES];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bundleItemDetails" sender:self.tableView];
```

}

I get the index values but I still have empty itemCell (itemCell is a custom cell with an external .xib, could this need to be called differently in a UIViewController than in a UITableviewController?

Comment: send the self [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bundleItemDetails" sender:self];

Comment: Already tried that, same result, cell is nil

Comment: so uo add self.tableview.datasource=self and self.tableview.delegate=self ?

Comment: yes, both are set to self

Comment: tell me you used a NSMutableArray for filling your tableView ?

Comment: it's an NSArray with Dictionaries in it

Comment: the thing that confuses me is that it works with a UITableViewController and it doesn't with a UIViewController without changing almost anything (besides removing delegates and changing sender from tableView to self or self.tableView)

Comment: can you add all your code here  ?

Comment: You are passing sender:tableView to performSegueWithIdentifier, but it is not using sender. When you are switching type of view controller, what else are you changing? Is your tableView set as an outlet with that exact name when using a UIViewController?

Comment: yes this is what i have in header for tableView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Comment: Is self.tableView nil? I've have you connected it in IB?

Comment: The table is populated with data and I have an external xib for the table cell. The data comes from a json object and everything works perfectly until the user taps on a cell (and only in a uiviewctrl with a uitableview in it). Then the cell (NSLogging it) returns nil

Comment: Why don't you connect the segue directly from the cell, and then the sender argument in prepareForSegue:sender: will be the cell?

Comment: The main difference between a UIViewController with a UITableView and a UITableViewController is that in the former you need to make sure you have connected everything from IB to your IBOutlets.  In a UITableViewController the connections are made for you - hence my question is `self.tableView` nil? It will be if you haven't explicitly connected your tableview to your IBOutlet in IB

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I did, it shows a dot inside the circle in it's declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using properties to hold the values you want to pass in the segue. You would set the properties in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and then access them in `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.valueImage = cell.itemImage.image;
    // etc...

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bundleItemDetails" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"bundleItemDetails"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
        itemDetails *bundleProducts = (itemDetails*)([navController viewControllers][0]);

        bundleProducts.valueImage = self.valueImage;
        bundleProducts.valueName = self.valueName;
        bundleProducts.valueDescription = self.valueDescription;
        bundleProducts.detailFullPrice.text = self.detailFullPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work in order to solve my problem, but I still don't get it why it doesn't need this in a UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

Check if your tableView `tableView.allowsSelection` is `YES`

Comment: I checked it and I have also tried to explicitly set it as YES, no change